# Error Equation of a Control Loop

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory, modeling

I want to calculate the error of a control loop. Therefore, the system and the general processes and models are defined as follows:[image] [image]

The equation for error is described as follows:
[image]

I do not understand how they eliminate the denominator in the first term (1 + A1s + . . + Ans^n) and the denominator (B0 + B1s + . .  + Bms^m) in the second term.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nothing has been eliminated :) It looks like $M_1(s) = (b_0 + b_1s + ... + b_ms^m)$ and $M_2^{-1}(s) = (a0 + a_1s + ... + a_ns^n)$

Comment: You're right, thank you. I didn't pay attention to the nomination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is stated in your equation:
$M_1(s)\,M_2(s) = (bo + B_1s + \cdots + b_m\,s^m)\frac{1}{1+a_1\,s+\cdots+a_n\,s^n} $ from here we observe that

- $M_1(s) = bo + B_1s + \cdots + b_m\,s^m$ , and
- $M_2^{-1}(s) = 1+a_1\,s+\cdots+a_n\,s^n$.

From your block diagram we can observe that $$e(s)= Y(s)\,M_2^{-1} - U(s)\, M_1(s)$$
Replacing the above equations, gives us the result you were seeking, and as @Lidell says, nothing is eliminated.